# Could not load file or assembly 'log4net

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, log4net

Ok I am having a very odd issue when deploying one of our web applications to our live servers.

Our application uses log4net to log a lot of actions quite heavily and after a couple of hours after being deployed we get the following exception.

Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b32731d11ce58905' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

Here are the relevant web.config additions I use.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>

<log4net>
    <appender name="ErrorLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="D:\SomeLocation\Errorlog"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size"/>
      <param name="maxSizeRollBackups" value="-1" />
      <param name="maximumFileSize" value="100MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="FATAL" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="BookingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="D:\SomeLocation\BookingInfoLog"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size"/>
      <param name="maxSizeRollBackups" value="-1" />
      <param name="maximumFileSize" value="100MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="BookingLogFileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorLogFileAppender"/>
    </root>

  </log4net>
```

It is working fine on our local machines an dev server but just not on the live.

Incidentally it seems to break after the JIT compiler runs on the server after a web.config update or an app pool recycle, or even just a long period of time!

**UPDATE:** Our live servers run all websites from a share location.  I managed to replicate this issue on another server running the application from a share.  When setting the site to run from a local drive the issue goes away but our hosting requires us to run from a share.  Any ideas why log4net would have permissions issues running from a share.  Again the app runs first time until another JIT compilation occurs

Comment: i am having exactly the same problem as you.  did you ever get a solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

We had this problem also when we moved to VS 2010 and .NET 4.0, we don't use log4net at all, but I suspect something else we use does (maybe Crystal Reports?) and I also suspect there is a dll we use that is a 32-bit dll as well because when I change the "Enable 32-Bit Applications" option under the advanced settings for the Application Pool in IIS to "True" everything worked again.

Comment: Thanks. I was just having this problem and your answer helped. But, oddly enough, I had the opposite problem. I had "Enable 32-bit Applications" set to "True", and it started working again when I set it to "False".

Comment: Note:  Per Matt's comment.  Crystal Reports was calling log4net.

Answer (score 6):

Probally asking the obvious but I'm assuming the log4net.dll in your bin folder is the correct version ?

if you have more than one project which references differnt versions of the same DLL its not uncommon for the later project to copy the DLL over the previous version.

Assuming that you have more than one copy of log4net needing to be supported the best solution I can think of is to add probing to you config and put this version in another folder.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx

Comment: Thats interesting,  We do have several projects running on that server using log4net.  I'm pretty sure they use the same version though, I will try your suggestion.  Even so why would running the project from a local drive work ok but not from a share?

Comment: A Share is only a partially trusted location by default you can add it to have full trust, I forget the command prompt name but there is ".NET Framework 2.0 Configuration" mmc Snap-in which can conifgure it for you.

Can you confirm that the version of log4net in your bin folder is version 1.2.9.0 and that the public key is correct? you can right click on the file and choose properties to find out.

Comment: Altough I didn't use the log4net.dll as a reference, it was in my bin folder. Once removed I didn't get the 500 error anymore...

Answer (score 1):

Check the version you bind in compile time (your file reference) and the version that is used runtime (first look in the GAC, then local)

Usually the version in the GAC differs from the version you have as file reference. Please check this.

Also cleanup the ASP.NET temp dir and execute IIS restart (cmd prompt -> iisreset)

Comment: But if we don't reference the GAC we just reference the dll.  Maybe my understanding of the GAC is incorrect?

Comment: Reference assemblies is always build-time, GAC is always runtime. Click on the assembly that is referenced in your C# project. Look at the signature. Then look in the GAC, check whether the assembly name is registered there. If so, check both versions (the one you referenced and the one in the GAC). When they differ you have a problem

Answer (score 0):

I bet your JIT compiler has no write access to the share. It seems like the JIT compiler recompiles the whole site from time to time, maybe when it gets recycled.

One options is to deploy the site prebuilt. That way there is no recompilation. The other option is that you give write access to the JIT complier to your share. Chances are it's the same user as the one that runs your web service, eg. SYSTEM, NETWORK SERVICE or LOCAL SERVICE groups or maybe one of the IIS_* users...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and if you use GIT this might help you.

The problem turned out to be that I had my Log4net.dll file inside a folder called **log**. The .gitignore configuration file excludes (by default) all folders called log.